# Remove all JavaScript event listeners of an element and its children?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to remove all event listeners of an element and its children? Something like:

```
myElem.removeEventListeners();
```

I need this because I have a complex element with events, and I need to create a copy of it -- like a static image that does not react to any events.

Comment: How are the events bound in the first place (eg `onclick=...`,  `addEventListener`, library, etc)?

Comment: addEventListener() is used. It is used for myElem and for some arbitrary children depending on conditional logic triggered by the user.

Comment: I take it you don't care about IE then (which uses `attachEvent`)? If that's the case, "copy" your element with `cloneNode(true)`, and magic-boom-presto, addEventListener events will not get copied. It's in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you use `cloneNode`, the event listeners **won't be copied**.

If you want a robust solution your best bet is probably to write a wrapper to `attach/detach` listeners, and keep track of them yourself. Something like **[Dean Edwards' addEvent](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/)**.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am using W3C event listeners, so, I probably have to write a wrapper, which I would like to avoid...

Comment: but if you use `cloneNode` your listeners won't be copied. See my update,

Comment: still if there is a simple way to remove all event handler, that'd be great

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I can't use that with `window` object.

Answer (score -7):

I do not know of one, and a search on Google didn't yield any obvious results. One easy, kludgy solution is to create a function that cycles through every event and sets it to `null`, such as

```
function removeEvents(obj)
{
    obj.onblur = null;
    obj.onchange = null;
    obj.onclick = null;
    // ...
}
```

Call this function as follows: `removeEvents(myElem)`. A complete list of JavaScript event handlers can be found at http://www.elated.com/articles/events-and-event-handlers/.

Undoubtedly there is a more elegant way to write this function, but I don't know if there is a more elegant way to solve this problem. It would be lovely if someone knows of one. If you are binding events through a JavaScript library, such as jQuery, there may be other, better options.

Comment: I'd set it to an empty function (`function () {}`) instead in case it still gets called.

Comment: Depending on the browser, elements with no event handler have it set to either undefined or null. I don't think setting it to null presents any problems, but if so your suggestion should be taken.

Comment: Why is this downvoted to holy hell? Is it a bad idea, if your stuck in legacy code and can't bolt on an event library?

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem - it just wastes cycles with hope.

Comment: In what JS will that actually solve the problem?

Comment: someone took the time and effort to actually get out of his normal life and post an answer, he made an attempt, why criticise the guy. if its wrong, then it's wrong. how wil forums ever succeed if people get kicked in the ass for making a suggestion. why dont you go on and criticise all those other people that leach off every one of your priceless answers?! @TNi from everyone that uses forums sensibly, thank you for your effort.

Comment: @CraigWayne Stack Overflow is not a forum

Comment: This might have been a viable solution for your particular browser. It does not, however, work on the latest version (as of today) of Firefox or Chromium on Linux. It's also not documented anywhere in the ECMAScript standard as a possible solution, and therefore this is not likely to be a working solution for many people at all. While I can appreciate the idea, there's no explanation for WHY this might work, and that's why it's not a very good solution. Because then the solution is guesswork. I'm tired, I may not be saying anything cohesive.

Comment: What is wrong with this solution? [Clearly](https://medium.com/@annapeterson89/addeventlistener-vs-onclick-which-one-should-you-draft-into-your-fantasy-football-team-16ea9ae71ee0) `elt.onclick = callback` and `elt.addEventListener('click`, callback)` work differently. The latter is better to use because, you don't override existing events. But that's key for this question. Simply using `elt.onclick = () => {}` will override all events with a useless one. So you can start using `addEventListener` to add new events to a pretty much a clean slate.