# Behavior of removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Please check the below code:

```
var clickfn = function(){
 alert("clicked");                    
}
document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("click",clickfn,true);
clickfn = function(){  };
document.getElementById("div1").removeEventListener("click");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qUtzL/4/

Why does the `removeEventListener` does not work?

Comment: With [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener), two arguments are required; only the third argument is optional.

Comment: Related: [How to remove all listeners in an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251837/how-to-remove-all-listeners-in-an-element)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`removeEventListener` takes 2 parameters, the event, and the function to remove.
This should work:

```
document.getElementById("div1").removeEventListener("click", clickfn);
```

---

Also, the function you're executing is empty.

```
var clickfn = function(){  };
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought the removeEventListener("click") will remove all the function bound to it.My bad

Comment: what if I have a callback function to remove (anonymous)? I pass the function itself but doesn't seem to work

Comment: You need to pass a reference to the function you want to remove, @emreozgun10. So you’ll need to store that anonymous callback somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

You have to specify the exact function you've specified to `addEventListener` as the second argument. If you specified the third `useCapture` argument, you'll have to specify the same and equivalent to `removeEventListener` as well.

For example:

```
function myFunc(event){ alert(event.target.textContent); }

var myElement=document.getElementById('myElement');

//Add EventListener
myElement.addEventListener('click', myFunc, false );

/* ... */

//Remove EventListener
myElement.removeEventListener('click', myFunc, false );
```

↪ [View an example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsAXY/)

You can find more information at the [Mozilla Developer wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener).

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this issue with the Navbar code in ReactJS to give the Navbar a background color after scrolling 100px on the y-axis and remove it if the page view is within 100px of the top.

All I had to do is introduce a reverse function in the removeEventListener to give it the rules for application.

```html
const [show, handleShow] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        // do this
        handleShow(true);
      } else handleShow(false);
    });
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (window.scrollY < 100) {
          // do this
          handleShow(false);
        } else handleShow(true);
      });
    };
  });
```