# Is there a vanilla function to remove all event listeners without affecting the descendant nodes?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251837/how-to-remove-all-listeners-in-an-element) is essentially what I'm asking but with the restriction of not removing events for the descendant nodes.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQtbb/1/) I attempt to remove attached listeners by removing it from the DOM and placing it back.

```js
function removeListeners(el) {
    var par = el.parentNode;
    var place = el.nextSibling;
    par.removeChild(el);
    par.insertBefore(el, place);
}
```

Unfortunately this didn't work, you can still click to get the background to change (which is actually good, I never knew you could attach events without the element being in the DOM).

Given that discovery I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wQtbb/2/)

```js
function removeListeners(el) {
    var par = el.parentNode;
    var clone = el.cloneNode(false);
    par.replaceChild(clone, el);

    for (var index = 0; index < el.childNodes.length; ++index)
        clone.appendChild(el.childNodes[index]);
}
```

Which tries to do a shallow clone then copy all the decendants back in, but it doesn't copy all the children.

The [aforementioned question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251837/how-to-remove-all-listeners-in-an-element#9251864) said that "[if you want to have the children keep their listeners] you'll have to resort to explicitly removing listeners one at a time". I don't know how you would implement that.
I assume he means getting a list of the event types and removing the listeners for each in turn ([like jQuery can](http://api.jquery.com/off/)). Not only would that be impossible for [custom events](http://jsfiddle.net/qWhtk/) but vanilla JS has [no such functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) (you must specify the function to remove).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get my second attempt working.
And then, thanks to @JulianDescottes noting of my oversight, I've made this more concise version.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hq8vx/5/)'s the working code.

```js
function removeListeners(el) {
    //only replace the ancestor element
    var clone = el.cloneNode(false);

    //copy children backwards because of the removal
    for (var index = el.childNodes.length - 1; index >= 0; --index)
        clone.insertBefore(el.childNodes[index], clone.firstChild);

    //insert back into DOM
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, el);
}
```

---

I was hoping for something more native, I fear there are unforeseen consequences using this method, I don't like removing things from the DOM and expecting them to work properly after.
At least it is more efficient than current suggestions, and if anyone comes up with something nicer I would be obliged (and thankful) to accept your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Node.childNodes is not an Array, but a **NodeList** (see [NodeList on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNodeList)). It is updated dynamically when the DOM is updated.

In your case you were emptying the childNodes collection as you were moving the elements to a new parentNode.

You can either copy the childNodes into an array using `Array.prototype.slice` or iterate backwards.

```
function removeListeners(el) {
    var par = el.parentNode;
    var clone = el.cloneNode(false);
    par.replaceChild(clone, el);

    for (var index = el.childNodes.length - 1; index >= 0; --index)
        clone.insertBefore(el.childNodes[index], clone.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Comment: that makes sense. So it would've worked if I iterated backwards? [I tried it](http://jsfiddle.net/hq8vx/2/), youre right, upvoted

Comment: You could have iterated backwards, but then it would have been a pain to insert the elements in the right order in your new clone. Copying the childNodes to an Array as you did here is easier to understand.

Comment: oh, and by bug I meant in my code (not of the browser, obviously). In which case it was definitely a bug

Comment: Ok, my mistake. Added your implementation to my answer.