# How to unbind all attached events on a given DOM in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say some DOM node (like a `<a>` tag) is bind with some events, like click to open a popup or anything. But I can't read the code which contains the binding stuff. How do I unbind them all? Is there any simple way/hack?

update again:

--

I checked the `Elements > Event Listeners` with my Chrome and found that there is a click event handler on my `a`, to make sure I am right, I tried the following steps:

First, I manually added a click handler from the console like this:

```
$a.click(function(){console.log(1)});
```

And I go back to the listeners tab, hit the refresh button, there is one more (now two handlers).

Then I use:

```
$a.off();
```

And I go back again, the one that I manually added is gone, remains only one handler (the one I want to git rid of)

And I used the replace-node way, and go back again, I found that the click handler is totally gone. That is what I want.

So, it's like `$a.off()` is not working, even though it's pretty sure that the event is bind to the element itself, not its parent nodes.

--

update:

1. I am using jQuery
2. I tried `$.unbind()` and `$.off()`, neither works
3. I used `$('#myEl').replaceWith($('#myEl').clone());` and this works fine. But it seems this way is not very perfect.

Comment: `$.off()` is supposed to work. If it doesn't you need to provide more information.

Comment: If `off` isn't working it may be they were delegated events. Can the poster confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a clone of the element and replace it. Cloning an element will not clone the attached event listeners.

```
var original = document.getElementById('id'),
var clone = original.cloneNode(true);

original.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, original);
```

Comment: Seems a lot like this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251837/how-to-remove-all-listeners-in-an-element

Comment: This will also remove all event handlers from the children.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to do that. Depending on which modifications have been made to the element, you could *clone* the node, move the children and replace the original with its clone:

```
var clone = element.cloneNode();
while (element.firstChild) {
  clone.appendChild(element.lastChild);
}
element.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, element);
```

[`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) will copy all the attributes, but not any changes that have been made to DOM properties.

Comment: This is the best answer as it saves the children! No children left behind!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use jquery .unbind():

```
$('a').unbind()
```

In new version jquery, .off() is suggest to use.

```
$('a').off()
```

if this not working, it means your event is not binding on this element but others like parent element, you may have this code in your script, and you have to decide how to deal with that:

```
$('.parent').on('click','a',callback);
```

Comment: I did use jQuery but this is not working. The event fires anyway.

Comment: Well from jquerys docs: `Calling .off() with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements.` Of course if these events are attached by delegation this will not work.

Comment: I've updated my question. Would you please take a look again? thanks!