# Remove node + even listeners of a createTextNode without parent

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a JS-created text node `var node = document.createTextNode(null)` that I'm binding custom events to:

```
node.addEventListener('customEvent', function(){
  console.log('hi');
}, false);
node.dispatch('customEvent');
```

Once I'm done, I'd like to cleanly remove the node + the event listeners.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251837/how-to-remove-all-listeners-in-an-element) that the simplest way to do that (not having to keep a reference to the callback because I have several), is to remove the node itself.

To do that, the method is `node.parentNode.removeChild(node);`.

Fine, but in my case `node.parentNode` is `null`.

How do I do?

I tried `document.removeChild(node);` as I thought the actual parent would be `document`, but I get: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

Comment: Why are you creating a text node you never add to a document and sending events to it?

Comment: Does your JS work? Please provide [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've created the node but never attached it to a document, all that's necessary to release it and the things it refers to (its event handlers) is to release all references to it. In your case, if `node` is the only thing that references it, then:

```
node = null; // or undefined, or 42, doesn't matter
```