# remove event listener in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I wants to remove event listener that are already in event listener.My Code is

```
  public componentDidMount() {
this.drags();
}
private drags(){
 const e = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.container);
    if (e) {
      e.addEventListener("mousedown", (event: any) => {
      ....
       parent = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode;
       if (parent) {
         parent.addEventListener("mousemove", (event1: any) => {
         ....
         const eDrag = parent.getElementsByClassName("draggable");
          eRes[0].addEventListener("mouseup", (event3: any) => {
          **// HERE I WANT TO REMOVE LISTENER OF PARENT OF MOUSE MOVE**
          }
        }
       }

    }
  }

}
```

Can anybody help me in this ?

Comment: Use [**removeEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) - You need to match the listener, best done with "named" listeners, as explained in the linked Documentation above, i.e: `parent.addEventListener("mousemove", yourNamedHandler)` then do `parent.removeEventListener("mousemove", yourNamedHandler)` - This is basic JavaScript and you should find lots of examples on SO, Google and the linked MDN Documentation.

Comment: If you just want to brute force remove any/all event listeners instead of removing them individually from an element you are quicker cloning the element and replacing it as that removes all listeners as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251837/how-to-remove-all-listeners-in-an-element

Answer (score 1):

Do not use anonymous function as the event handler, use a named function instead.

So, if you add the listener this way:

```
function doSomething() {
  // something 
}

window.addEventListener('mousedown', this.doSomething);
```

You can remove it like:

```
window.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.doSomething);
```

Comment: As Per code , mouseup event is adding in mousemove event which is parent. Now from child , i wants to remove parent mousemove listener.

Comment: Of course, the point is using named function. Have you tried to do parent.removeEventListener, but actually using named function?