# stop all triggered events for a javascript code block

Tags: javascript, events

Is there a way to catch each event triggered by block of code and stop its propagation?

Something like

```
stopAllEvent(function(){
// some code that could trigger some events
//...
});
```

and each event triggered inside the function must be "stopped"...

Exists a way to do this?

Comment: Sounds either like an XY problem, or a problem that needs additional context for a reasonable answer. (why would a function to `stopAllEvent` *trigger* additional events, doesn't that defeat the purpose?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all listeners in an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251837/how-to-remove-all-listeners-in-an-element)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've ah helper `clearValue` function that receive an HTML input(also more complex object of some javascript library) and clear it, but in some case I need that the function don't throw the event `change`

Comment: Can't you just add that logic to the clearValue function?