# Add / remove event listeners and this context inside a class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to conditionally add and remove event listeners on a button when the window is resized. To be able to remove the event listener, it has to be a named function.

The problem is it messes with `this` context, and therefore `this.element` in my `handle()` function is not accessible.

I can bind `this` and pass it along:

```
this.button.addEventListener('click', this.handle.bind(this));
```

But then it does not get removed, as it appears to not be the same event listener. Can i pass `this` differently, or is there some other way to remove event listeners? I have tried to clone the element and replace it, but then the event listener does not get reattached.

As per here: [How to remove all listeners in an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251837/how-to-remove-all-listeners-in-an-element)

Here is some simplified code:

```
export default class Classname {

  constructor(element, button) {
    this.button = button;
    this.element = document.querySelector(element);
    this.resize();
  }

  handle() {
    // do stuff
    console.log(this.element);
  }

  clickEvents() {
    if (condition) {
      this.button.addEventListener('click', this.handle);
    } else {
      this.button.removeEventListener('click', this.handle);
    }
  }

  resize() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      this.clickEvents();
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note: it might not be the best idea to bind a click event listener repeatedly during a resize event, unless you are very sure the `condition` evaluates to true once. Otherwise you might risk binding multiple identical event listeners.

Comment: @ Terry: No worries,  `resize` is wired via `debounce`, and the condition is a media query breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the bound handler to a property of the instance, and then pass that bound handler to both `addEventListener` and, later, `removeEventListener`:

```
clickEvents() {
  if (condition) {
    this.boundHandler = this.handle.bind(this);
    this.button.addEventListener('click', this.boundHandle);
  } else {
    this.button.removeEventListener('click', this.boundHandle);
  }
}
```

Another possibility would be to bind in the constructor instead:

```
constructor(element, button) {
  this.boundHandler = this.handle.bind(this);
  this.button = button;
  this.element = document.querySelector(element);
  this.resize();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `handle` method to an arrow function and then the `this` will be retained.

```
  handle = () => {
    // do stuff
    console.log(this.element);
  }
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =