# How to remove all event listeners of certain elements without its child's

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I remove event listeners of for example `$('table td')` but not its child's elements event listeners? (I have a table with button in its cells)
I tried it with `.off()` but it doesn't work.

edit: For example I have a table cell with some text and a button in it. Now `td` and `button` have their own event listeners. I want to remove only the event listener of `td` without removing event listener of `button`. I know I could just add event listener back to the button after it's removed, but that solution would cause a lot of problems in my case.

Comment: Can you create a demo of what you are currently working with please or at least include the relevant source code? Thank you.

Comment: Using `.off()` on an element like `td` does not actually remove the event handlers of the childs... Have a look at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/gErZKp?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working using namespaces as `on('click.namespace', function(){...})`.
Thank you for help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've seen answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251837/how-to-remove-all-listeners-in-an-element), since you mention not removing event listeners on child elements. Of course doing a deep clone won't work, but what can work is to do a shallow clone, and then transfer the child nodes to the clone. It's a little more work, but it will do what you want.

The main work is in the `setTimeout`, all the rest is really just setup.

Here I'm attaching two click event listeners: one to the button and one to the container div. before the 5 second `setTimeout`, clicking the button will fire both listeners (so you'll see console logs for both BUTTON and DIV). After the timer, you'll still see the BUTTON event.

```js
var rem = document.getElementById('rem');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
function onClick(e) {
  var t = e.currentTarget
  console.log(t.tagName);
}
rem.addEventListener('click', onClick);
btn.addEventListener('click', onClick);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('removing events from div');

  // shallow clone
  var rem2 = rem.cloneNode(false);

  // make and extract range to doc fragment 
  // for all contents of original div
  var range = document.createRange(); 
  range.setStartBefore(rem.firstChild);
  range.setEndAfter(rem.lastChild);
  var documentFragment = range.extractContents();

  // append doc fragment to clone
  // insert clone and remove old div
  rem2.appendChild(documentFragment);
  document.body.insertBefore(rem2, rem);
  rem.remove();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div id='rem'>
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <button id='btn'>click me</button>
  <p>paragraph <b>bold</b> stuff</p>
</div>
```