# Click keeps increment Firestore update value each time

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
function rateProject(self) {

document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[5].style.display="block";
var docRef=self.getAttribute("id");
var downloadRef = db.collection("projects").doc(docRef);

    document.getElementById('rateOneStar').addEventListener('click',e=>{
        return downloadRef.update({
            oneStar: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log("1 star given");
            document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[5].style.display="none";
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // The document probably doesn't exist.
            console.error("Error updating document: ", error);

        });

    })
}
```

> This is what happens to oneStar:

(1 click: 1), (2 click: 3), (3 click: 6)

> What I want:

(1 click: 1), (2 click: 2), (3 click: 3).

> If I remove the eventListener it works.

Comment: I don't understand is this a question? What your problem? Your code works properly though. You are using FieldValue.increment(1) which increases the value of the field by 1. If the value was 3 and you run it will go to 4.

Comment: Thanks for responding! If I click 3 times the field value will be 6, not 3 as I want. If I click four times the value will be 10 not 4 as I want. Each time I click the increment value becomes one more. I want the increment value to be constant. Hope you understand the problem better.

Comment: how many times do you call the function rateProject?

Comment: It depends on how many times the user clicks a project(object). I got many different projects, and the function will launch when I user clicks on one of the projects. Of course I want the user to be able to click on every project visible, but the user don't have to. So it really depends on what the user does. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `addEventListener` is stacking up and each time you execute the function one more listener is added. If you want to confirm that this is happening by clicking 4 times the result should be 10. One possible solution is to clear the events listener each time from the element `rateOneStar`.

Comment: I can confirm that by clicking four times the result is 10. How to I clear the event listener?

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251837/how-to-remove-all-listeners-in-an-element Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer helped you mark it as accepted, so other people don't waste time trying to answer an already answered question.