# Webpack-hot-middleware multiplies event listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, webpack-hot-middleware

While trying to set up my new development environment (node server + client with only vanilla js on board), I faced with webpack-hot-middleware for hot reloading my front-end changes. And everything would be fine, but if there are any code like this

```
$button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // any code here
});
```

than after hot reloading, when you click on $button, this event listener will fire one more time than before! Terribly uncomfortable, but I did not found any reports of a similar problem from anyone. Can anyone help me with possible workarounds of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the [webpack hot module replacement documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#gotchas), which describes how to handle issues like this.

Basically, when your code changes you'll need to update the event binding using `module.hot.accept` with something like this.

```js
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./yourCode.js', function() {
    console.log('Accepting the updated yourCode module!');

    $button.removeEventListener('click', oldHandler);
    $button.addEventListener('click', newHandler);
  })
}
```

The tricky bit will be clearing event listeners properly, since you'll need to have a reference to the original handler or you'll need to [clear all handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9251864/2178159).