# Disable NVDA from reading 'clickable' for series highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

How can I prevent NVDA screen reader from reading 'clickable' for series Highcharts? The series values are wrapped inside a "tspan" tag and don't have any click event associated with it. Thanks for the help in advance.

[image]

Adding a 2nd screenshot (I'll attach a fiddle once I figure it out) in response to Graham Ritchie's comment.[image]

```js
window.EJ = window.EJ || {},
  EJ.features = EJ.features || {};



EJ.events = {};
(function(q) {
  'use strict';

 var topics = {},
  subUid = -1;

 q.subscribe = function(topic, func) {
  if (!topics[topic]) {
   topics[topic] = [];
  }

  var token = (++subUid).toString();
  topics[topic].push({
   token: token,
   func: func
  });

  return token;
 };

 q.publish = function(topic, args) {
  if (!topics[topic]) {
   return false;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
   var subscribers = topics[topic],
    len = subscribers ? subscribers.length : 0;

   while (len--) {
    subscribers[len].func(topic, args);
   }
  }, 0);

  return true;
 };

 q.unsubscribe = function(token) {
  for (var m in topics) {
   if (topics[m]) {
    for (var i = 0, j = topics[m].length; i < j; i++) {
     if (topics[m][i].token === token) {
      topics[m].splice(i, 1);
      return token;
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return false;
 };
}(EJ.events));
/**
 * Features loader
 * Iterates over all data-features attributes in the DOM and will execute EJ.features.featureName.init()
 */

EJ.features = {
 init: function() {
  var features = $('[data-features]');
  if (!features.length) return false;
  for (var i = 0, n = features.length; i < n; i++) {
   var $el = $(features[i]),
    func = $el.data('features');
   if (this[func] && typeof this[func].init === 'function') {
    this[func].init($el);
   }
  }
 }
};

EJ.features.careerFitTool = (function(quiz) {
 quiz.init = function(el) {

  if (!el) {
   throw new Error('You must supply the constructor an element instance to operate on.');
  }

  var currQuestionIndex = -1,
   $start = el.find('.quiz-start'),
   $finish = el.find('.quiz-finish'),
   $startOver = el.find('.quiz-startOver'),
   $previousQuestion = el.find('.previous-question'),
   $nextQuestion = el.find('.next-question'),
   $stateDefault = el.find('.state-default'),
   $stateActive = el.find('.state-quiz'),
   $questions = el.find('.question-field'),
   $progressIndicator = el.find('.progress-indicator'),
   numOfQuestions = $questions.length
  $answers = el.find('.answer');

  var faPct = 0;
  var boaPct = 0;
  var hqPct = 0;

  $previousQuestion.on('click', function() {
   changeQuestion('prev');
  });
  $nextQuestion.on('click', function() {
   changeQuestion('next');
  });

  $start.on('click', function() {
   changeState('default', 'quiz');
  });
  $finish.on('click', function() {
   changeState('quiz', 'finished');
  });

  $startOver.on('click', function() {
   changeState('finished', 'default');
   currQuestionIndex = -1;
   $(el).find('form')[0].reset();
      focusLetsGetStarted();
  });

  $answers.on('change', function() {
   $nextQuestion.removeClass('disabled')
    .attr('disabled', false);
  })

  /**
   * Change state of quiz.
   * @param  {string} currState Current state (default/quiz/finished)
   * @param  {string} nextState Desired next state (default/quiz/finished)
   */
  function changeState(currState, nextState) {
   el.find('.state-' + currState).hide();
   el.find('.state-' + nextState).show();

   if (currState === 'default') {
    $previousQuestion.hide();
    $($questions[++currQuestionIndex]).show();
    $($progressIndicator[currQuestionIndex]).addClass('active');
   }
  }


  function computeJobFitPercents() {
   var faAmount = 0;
   var boaAmount = 0;
   var hqAmount = 0;
   var totalOptionAmount = 0;
   var faPercent = 0;
   var boaPercent = 0;
   var hqPercent = 0;


   for (var i = 1; i <= 45; i++) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('group' + i);
    for (var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
     var radio = radios[j];
     var radioString = radio.value;
     if (radioString.indexOf("Financial Advisor") >= 0 && radio.checked) {
      faAmount++;
     }
     if (radioString.indexOf("Branch Office Administrator") >= 0 && radio.checked) {
      boaAmount++;
     }
     if (radioString.indexOf("Headquarters") >= 0 && radio.checked) {
      hqAmount++;
     }
    }
    totalOptionAmount = faAmount + boaAmount + hqAmount;
    faPercent = parseFloat(((faAmount / totalOptionAmount) * 100).toFixed());
    boaPercent = parseFloat(((boaAmount / totalOptionAmount) * 100).toFixed());
    hqPercent = parseFloat(((hqAmount / totalOptionAmount) * 100).toFixed());
    var totalPercent = faPercent + boaPercent + hqPercent;
   }

   generatePieChart(faPercent, boaPercent, hqPercent);


   // Populate the variables required to display the result
   faPct = faPercent;
   boaPct = boaPercent;
   hqPct = hqPercent;

  }

  /**
   * This function generates pie chart for the given inputs.
   * It generates a job fir graph for the questions answered by the user.
   */
  function generatePieChart(faPrcnt, boaPrcnt, hqPrcnt) {

   Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#F3BD06', '#f6d050 ', '#fae49b']
   });

   // Build the chart
   $('#pieChartContainer').highcharts({
    chart: {
     plotBackgroundColor: null,
     plotBorderWidth: null,
     plotShadow: false,
     width: 230

    },

    credits: {
     enabled: false
    },

    title: {
     text: null
    },

    scrollbar : {
     enabled : false
                },

    tooltip: {
     enabled: false,
     pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },

    plotOptions: {
     pie: {
      allowPointSelect: false,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
       enabled: false
      },
      showInLegend: true,
      borderWidth: 0,
      point: {
       events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
         //pieChart.tooltip.hide();
        }
       }
      }
     }
    },

    exporting: {
     enabled: false
    },

    legend: {
     layout: 'vertical',
     floating: false,
     borderRadius: 0,
     borderWidth: 0,
     align: 'center',
     verticalAlign: 'bottom',
     labelFormatter: function() {
      return this.y + '%' + ' ' + '-' + this.name;
     }
    },

    series: [{
     type: 'pie',
     name: 'Career Chart',
     point: {
      events: {
       legendItemClick: function() {
        return false;
       }
      }
     },
     data: [
      ['Financial Advisor', faPrcnt],
      ['Branch Office Administrator', boaPrcnt], {
       name: 'Headquarters',
       y: hqPrcnt,
       sliced: false,
       selected: false
      }
     ]
    }]
   });
  }


  /**
   * Go to previous or next question
   * @param  {string} direction 'next' or 'prev'
   * @return {boolean} are we on first or last question?
   */
  function changeQuestion(direction) {
   //Call function to compute the job fit percent as per the answers selected by the user
   //computeJobFitPercents();

   var questionAnswers;
   var isAnswered;

   $($questions[currQuestionIndex]).hide();
   $progressIndicator.removeClass('active');

   if (direction === 'next') {
    currQuestionIndex++;
   } else {
    currQuestionIndex--;
   }

   $($progressIndicator[currQuestionIndex]).addClass('active');

   questionAnswers = $($questions[currQuestionIndex]).find('.answer');

   for (var i = 0, j = questionAnswers.length; i < j; i++) {
    if ($(questionAnswers[i]).prop('checked') === true) {
     isAnswered = true;
    }
   }

   if (isAnswered) {
    $nextQuestion.removeClass('disabled')
     .attr('disabled', false);
   } else {
    $nextQuestion.addClass('disabled')
     .attr('disabled', true);
   }

   if (currQuestionIndex === -1) {
    $($questions[currQuestionIndex]).hide();
    changeState('quiz', 'default');
   } else if (currQuestionIndex === numOfQuestions) {
    //Call function to compute the job fit percent as per the answers selected by the user
    computeJobFitPercents();

    $($questions[currQuestionIndex]).hide();
    changeState('quiz', 'finished');

    //Determine the result
    $('#faOutcome').hide();
    $('#faResultLink').hide();
    $('#boaOutcome').hide();
    $('#boaResultLink').hide()
    $('#hqOutcome').hide();
    $('#hqResultLink').hide();

    if (faPct >= boaPct) {
     if (faPct >= hqPct) {
      $('#faOutcome').show();
      $('#faResultLink').show();
     } else {
      $('#hqOutcome').show();
      $('#hqResultLink').show();
     }
    } else if (boaPct >= hqPct) {
     $('#boaOutcome').show();
     $('#boaResultLink').show();
    } else {
     $('#hqOutcome').show();
     $('#hqResultLink').show();
    }
   } else {
    $($questions[currQuestionIndex]).show();

    if (currQuestionIndex === 0) {
     $previousQuestion.hide();
    } else {
     $previousQuestion.show();
    }
   }

   return currQuestionIndex === numOfQuestions || currQuestionIndex === 0;
  }
 }

 return quiz;
}(EJ.features.careerFitTool || {}));


EJ.initialize = function() {
  EJ.features.init();
};


$(function() {
 EJ.initialize();
 $('.comp-registrationForm.modal').modal('show');
});
```

```css
/* Enter Your Custom CSS Here */

input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"] {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
  margin: 4px 0 0;
 margin-top: 1px \9;
/* IE8-9 */
 line-height: normal;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}

input[type="file"]:focus,input[type="radio"]:focus,input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
 outline: thin dotted #333 !important;
  outline-offset: -2px !important;
  outline-color: #000 !important;
}

.radio,.checkbox {
 display: block;
 min-height: 20px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.radio label,.checkbox label {
 display: inline;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-weight: 400;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.radio input[type="radio"],.radio-inline input[type="radio"],.checkbox input[type="checkbox"],.checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
 float: left;
 margin-left: -20px;
}

.radio + .radio,.checkbox + .checkbox {
 margin-top: -5px;
}

.radio-inline,.checkbox-inline {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-weight: 400;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-inline + .radio-inline,.checkbox-inline + .checkbox-inline {
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

input[type="radio"][disabled],fieldset[disabled] input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"][disabled],fieldset[disabled] input[type="checkbox"],.radio[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .radio,.radio-inline[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .radio-inline,.checkbox[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .checkbox,.checkbox-inline[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .checkbox-inline {
 cursor: not-allowed;
}

/*
# Button Primary
 */

.button,.button-cta,.button-cta-floating,.button-previous,.button-download,.button-expand,.button-arrow-only {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #f8512e;
 border-color: #f96141;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
 -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-out;
 transition: background-color .25s ease-out;
 font-family: "Proxima Nova-Semibold",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 1;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}


.pull-right {
 float: right !important;
}

.hide {
 display: none !important;
}


.hidden {
 display: none !important;
 visibility: hidden !important;
}

/* start .comp-careerFitTool */
.comp-careerFitTool {
 background: #9b9998;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 position: relative;
}

.comp-careerFitTool:before,.comp-careerFitTool:after {
 content: " ";
/* 1 */
 display: table;
/* 2 */
}

.comp-careerFitTool:after {
 clear: both;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 470px) {
 .comp-careerFitTool {
  padding-bottom: 35px;
 }
}

.career-tool-intro {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
 .career-tool-intro h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
 }
}

.career-tool-intro p {
 margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 470px) {
 .career-tool-intro {
  padding: 25px;
 }
}

.career-tool-info {
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #9b9998;
 color: #5b5955;
 padding: 20px;
}

.career-tool-info:before,.career-tool-info:after {
 content: " ";
/* 1 */
 display: table;
/* 2 */
}

.career-tool-info:after {
 clear: both;
}

.career-tool-info input[type="radio"],.career-tool-info input[type="checkbox"] {
 margin-right: 5px;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.career-tool-info label {
 font-family: "Proxima Nova-Semibold",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 18px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 730px) and (max-width: 959px) {
 .career-tool-info .questions-intro {
  font-size: 20px;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
 .career-tool-info .questions-intro {
  font-size: 24px;
 }
}

.career-tool-info .questions {
 margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.career-tool-info .question {
 font-family: "Proxima Nova-Semibold",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 730px) and (max-width: 959px) {
 .career-tool-info .question {
  font-size: 20px;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
 .career-tool-info .question {
  font-size: 28px;
 }
}

.career-tool-info .question-field,.career-tool-info .question-changer,.career-tool-info .question-progress {
 padding-left: 50px;
}

.career-tool-info .question-field {
 position: relative;
}

.career-tool-info .question-number {
 font-family: "Proxima Nova-Bold",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 height: 31px;
 width: 31px;
 background: transparent url(https://cdn-static.findly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/936/2020/05/question-number.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 left: 2px;
 line-height: 33px;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 top: 4px;
}

.career-tool-info .question-changer {
 margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.career-tool-info .state,.career-tool-info .question-field {
 display: none;
}

.career-tool-info .state-default {
 display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1190px) {
 .career-tool-info .state-default .inner-wrap,.career-tool-info .state-finished .inner-wrap {
  font-size: 24px;
 }

 .career-tool-info .state-quiz {
  font-size: 20px;
 }
}

.career-tool-info .state .inner-wrap {
 float: left;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 730px) {
 .career-tool-info .state .inner-wrap {
  width: 60%;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1190px) {
 .career-tool-info .state .inner-wrap {
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-right: 25px;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 730px) {
 .career-tool-info .state .inner-wrap-right {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 729px) {
 .career-tool-info .state img.pull-right {
  display: none;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 730px) {
 .career-tool-info .state img.pull-right {
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  margin-right: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  width: 40%;
 }
}

.career-tool-info .quiz-startOver {
 text-decoration: underline;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 730px) {
 .career-tool-info .pie-chart,.career-tool-info .legend {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 1%;
  width: 48%;
 }
}

.career-tool-info .pie-chart img {
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 729px) {
 .career-tool-info .pie-chart {
  display: none;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 730px) {
 .career-tool-info .legend {
  margin-top: 20px;
 }
}

.career-tool-info .opportunity {
 margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.career-tool-info .opportunity:before,.career-tool-info .opportunity:after {
 content: " ";
/* 1 */
 display: table;
/* 2 */
}

.career-tool-info .opportunity:after {
 clear: both;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 470px) {
 .career-tool-info {
  padding: 25px;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 730px) {
 .career-tool-info .score,.career-tool-info .position {
  float: left;
 }

 .career-tool-info .score {
  width: 40%;
 }

 .career-tool-info .position {
  width: 60%;
 }

 .career-tool-info .key {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #fbc81b;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
 }

 .career-tool-info .key2 {
  background: #9b9998;
 }

 .career-tool-info .key3 {
  background: #3f3f3f;
 }
}

.progress-indicator {
 height: 18px;
 width: 18px;
 display: inline-block;
 *display: inline;
 *zoom: 1;
 background: transparent url(https://cdn-static.findly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/936/2020/05/progress-indicator.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.progress-indicator.active {
 background-image: url(https://cdn-static.findly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/936/2020/05/progress-indicator-active.png);
}

/* /end .comp-careerFitTool */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://careers.edwardjones.com/images/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <section class="comp-careerFitTool l-spacer" data-features="careerFitTool">
   <div class="career-tool-intro">
      <h2>Test highcharts after 3 questions</h2>
      <p>Find the Right Opportunity for You.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="career-tool-info">
      <form action="">
         <div class="state state-default">
            <div class="inner-wrap">
               <h3>Unsure of what role may be right for you?</h3>
               <p>Take a short quiz to see where your interests fit best at Edward Jones.</p>
               <p><a class="button-cta quiz-start" href="javascript:;">Let's get started</a></p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://cdn-static.findly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/936/2020/05/career-fit-tool.png" alt="Career fit tool" class="pull-right">
         </div>
         <div class="state state-quiz">
            <div class="questions">
               <fieldset id="questionDiv1" aria-live="assertive" class="question-field">
                  <legend>
                  <span aria-label="question number 1 of 8" class="question-number">1</span>
                  <p class="questions-intro">Please select the option below that best applies to you.</p>
                  <p class="question">The type of role that interests me more:</p>
                  </legend>
                  <div>
                  <p><label for="question100"> <input type="radio" id="question100" name="group1" class="answer" value="Financial Advisor">Entrepreneurial/Business Development</label></p>
                  <p><label for="question200"> <input type="radio" id="question200" name="group1" class="answer" value="Branch Office Administrator">Support someone building their business</label></p>
                  </div>
               </fieldset>
               <fieldset id="questionDiv2" aria-live="assertive" class="question-field">
                 <legend>
                  <img src="https://cdn-static.findly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/936/2020/05/career-fit-tool.png" alt="career fit tool" class="pull-right">
                  <span aria-label="question number 2 of 8" class="question-number">2</span>
                  <p class="questions-intro">Please select the option below that best applies to you.</p>
                  <p class="question">How I would like to be compensated for my work:</p>
                 </legend>
                  <div>
                  <p><label for="question101"> <input type="radio" id="question101" name="group2" class="answer" value="Financial Advisor">Commissions</label></p>
                  <p><label for="question201"> <input type="radio" id="question201" name="group2" class="answer" value="Branch Office Administrator,Headquarters">Salary or hourly</label></p>
                  </div>
               </fieldset>
               <fieldset id="questionDiv3" aria-live="assertive" class="question-field">
                 <legend>
                  <span aria-label="question number 3 of 8" class="question-number">3</span>
                  <p class="questions-intro">Please select the option below that best applies to you.</p>
                  <p class="question">My preferred work style:</p>
                  </legend>
                  <div>
                  <p><label for="question102"> <input type="radio" id="question102" name="group3" class="answer" value="Financial Advisor,Branch Office Administrator">Work autonomously</label></p>
                  <p><label for="question202"> <input type="radio" id="question202" name="group3" class="answer" value="Headquarters">Work collaboratively on a team</label></p>
                  </div>
               </fieldset>
              </div>
            <p aria-live="assertive" class="question-changer">
               <a aria-label="go to previous question" class="button-previous previous-question" href="javascript:;">Previous</a>
               <a aria-label="go to next question" class="button-cta next-question disabled" href="javascript:;">Next</a>
            </p>
            <p class="question-progress">
               <span aria-live="assertive" class="progress-indicator"></span>
               <span aria-live="assertive" class="progress-indicator"></span>
               <span aria-live="assertive" class="progress-indicator"></span>
            </p>
         </div>
         <div aria-live="assertive" class="state state-finished">
            <div class="inner-wrap">
               <h3>You're Finished</h3>
               <p>Based on your responses, we recommend you explore career opportunities as a</p>
               <p id="faOutcome">Financial Advisor</p>
               <p id="boaOutcome">Branch Office Administrator</p>
               <p id="hqOutcome">Headquarters Professional</p>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-wrap-right">
               <div id="pieChartContainer" tabindex="0"></div>
            </div>
            <p id="faResultLink">Discover more about this opportunity here <a href="/explore-opportunities/new-financial-advisors/index.html" class="button-arrow-only" title="Discover more about this opportunity here"> </a></p>
            <p id="boaResultLink">Discover more about this opportunity here <a href="/explore-opportunities/branch-support/index.html" class="button-arrow-only" title="Discover more about this opportunity here"> </a></p>
            <p id="hqResultLink">Discover more about this opportunity here <a href="/explore-opportunities/hq/index.html" class="button-arrow-only" title="Discover more about this opportunity here"> </a></p>
            <p><a class="quiz-startOver" href="javascript:;">Start Over</a></p>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It says clickable if you have a JS function attached to it. Go to the event listeners tab on the right, uncheck 'ancestors' and see if there are any event listeners attached. i would guess there are as there is `cursor: pointer` set in the styles. It could just be that these are empty event listeners added by highcharts. If you want to create a proper fiddle / snippet I will happily inspect further for you but from a screenshot of your console that is the best I think you will get as an answer I am afraid.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamRitchie for your input. I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm trying to find how to attach fiddle. Meanwhile I checked for the event listeners and there is a 'click' event added. I've attached a 2nd screenshot for this. Can you please tell how to remove this event because it's coming from highcharts?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I've attached a 2nd screenshot.

Comment: Right so what you need to do is remove those event listeners (assuming they don't do anything, yet again can't see that). Here(1) is an answer that shows how to do that, if that works then I will turn it into a full answer for you. Obviously you will have to adjust this to work on a class rather than an ID but hopefully that won't be too difficult....(1 = https://stackoverflow.com/a/9251864/2702894). I would guess that `highcharts-legend-item` could be specific enough for your selector.

Comment: To create a fiddle you can press `ctrl` + `m` when you are editing the question, or click the icon next to the picture icon with the `<>` on it. This then lets you add HTML, CSS, JS just like codepen or jsfiddle. If you can do that it makes life a lot easier for us when we try and answer for you :-)

Comment: Thanks @GrahamRitchie, that really helped me a lot. I've now added a fiddle and you'll now be able to run the code snippet. Hope this helps now. Actually at the end of 3rd question, a pie chart is supposed to open up with legend below. Not sure why it's not showing up. So coming back to my 'clickable' issue, I think we need to add some parameter inside this - $('#pieChartContainer').highcharts({...});. I'm going through their documentation and still not able to figure out how to prevent the screenreader from reading 'clickable'.

Comment: It is bad practice for someone to fix your fiddles but just so you know you have the load order wrong (highcharts should be last script you include) and you have jquery UI set to http rather than https so it is getting blocked as "mixed content". There is a problem with your tooltip hide once you correct those errors it is referencing `pieChart` but there is no variable with that name. (`pieChart.tooltip.hide();`). Fix those errors if you can. I will keep helping you bit by bit until we can get to a point where we can remove those event listeners (we need to get rid of all errors first :-) )