# Reset element click listener to default behavior JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, onclicklistener

Let's say i have a anchor tag which has a listener set by some library (that is using the class to add it, which is also used to add style, therefore I can't just remove the class from the element).

Let's also say that I don't want that listener anymore, and so I would like just to have the browser-default behavior, how do I reset it to default?

In this case we are talking of a anchor tag, but I would like to have a general solution to this.

Example:

```js
// library example code
[...document.getElementsByClassName("test")].forEach(el =>{
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    alert("wrong listener")
  })
})

// how to reset?
// document.getElementsByClassName("test").forEach(el => el.resetListeners())
//                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```css
.test{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="test">click me</a>
```

Comment: You can't since the attached functions are anonymous. You need the original function to remove the event listener

Comment: You can clone all your links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251837/how-to-remove-all-listeners-in-an-element

Comment: @ZachJensz that is so brute force. _I love it_

Comment: If the plugin targets a class, copy the ruleset of said class and give it a different name, then manually change classes or programmatically toggle classes.

Comment: so there is no way to get back a "default" event handler in js

Comment: Note that event handlers are bound to _elements_  and not to their class names. JavaScript does not work like CSS.

Comment: I know, it's a plugin targeting a class, don't know specifics.

Comment: Maybe if you know the class you could querySelectorAll that class and remove it that way