# Reassigned NodeList in ForEach Loop with list.js

Tags: javascript, foreach, nodelist, list.js

I'm using List.js to sort a HTML list.
The JS reorders the list items in the DOM.
Now I made elements in my list clickable and i need to use the (new) index of my list items.

Super Simple HTML setup:

```
<div id="mylist">
  <ul class="simple list">
    <li class="items">one</li>
    <li class="items">two</li>
    <li class="items">three</li>
    <li class="items">four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
let nodeList = getUpdatedList();

function getUpdatedList () {
  return document.querySelectorAll('.items');
}

// here comes the List.js setup
const list = new List("mylist", { "some options" });

// and here I reassign the new List to the nodeList variable
list.on('updated', ()=>{
  nodeList = getUpdatedList();
})

// print the index on click
nodeList.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(index);
  })
})
```

List.js works perfectly, the items are now reordered in the DOM after a sort method.
For example

```
  <ul class="simple list">
    <li class="items">three</li>
    <li class="items">four</li>
    <li class="items">two</li>
    <li class="items">one</li>
  </ul>
```

But when I click on the first item, the console still prints `4` (the old order) although I reassigned `nodelist` after list.js update.

Comment: How are you sorting?

Comment: @KostasMinaidis I call the list with buttons outside of my list, the [script](https://listjs.com) then reorders the list items and injects them into the DOM in new order.

Comment: Are you using the ul, li structure that you have pasted here or are there nested elements inside the li elements?

Answer (score 0):

When you do this part, you're adding an event listener to each button. The value of `index` is locked in at that point. Each click callback is a closure that contains its own `index` value.

```js
nodeList.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(index); // this will never change
  })
})
```

If you want the values to change, either re-assign the click handlers or re-write the click handler function to do some other kind of logic to check the new position.

Comment: I wrapped the whole forEach loop including the event listener inside the ListJSs `on("updated")` event, now the console prints the index twice (once the initial state, once the updated state) and after every new sort update once more, with the actual index at last position. But what I want is just the actual index.

Comment: Each time you do this, you are _adding_ a new event listener. If you want to get rid of the old listeners, you need to remove them. Otherwise there will be more and more listeners added to the items and they will all keep on firing on each click event. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251837/how-to-remove-all-listeners-in-an-element) for info on how to remove the old listeners before adding new ones. You can also use [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) as long as you keep a reference to the callback.

Comment: Of cooourse! Changed the `addEventListener()` to a `item.onclick` and it did the job! Thanks