# Javascript: remove all mouseover events from an object

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

This question asks about Google charts, **but is more general.**

Mouseover of the legend in my chart gives this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null

I haven't added any 'onmouseover' events, etc., it appears that it's just unhappy with the appearance of `null` in the series (when you plot two series with different x-values, Google charts says to add empty points as `null` and plot with `interpolateNull : true`).

Has anyone else had this problem? Is there a way to disable any mouseover events for the chart legend?

Thanks a lot for any advice you can give.

**Update:** [There is a minimal jsfiddle demonstrating this error here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y8jF/48/). It seems Google charts doesn't like having two x and y points that have the exact same values.

Comment: If you can provide a ([representative/minimal](http://sscce.org/)) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), we'll probably be able to help you out. Incidentally, post the representative code *here* too, make the question as self-contained as possible in order to retain its use for future visitors.

Comment: @DavidThomas I wasn't sure how to allow upload my XML data file with JSFiddle, so I just popped it here: http://colorfulengineering.org/test.html Note that this version has mouseover events, but even without them, anytime  the mouse hovers over the legend, it crashes.

Comment: I get no error or crash, Chrome v21 Ubuntu.

Comment: @dennmat Did you mouseover the legend of the first figure? If you do that and check the console, I get the error described (I just tried on Chrome 24.0.1312.69 Ubuntu).

Comment: @Oliver ahh I see yes, I do get the error, sorry I thought it was on the charts not on the legend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try stopping appropriate mouse events from reaching the built-in handlers.

This requires adding a `mouseover` listener to the chart's legend. 
The listener will call `event.stopPropagation()` (and surprisingly doesn't need to be triggered during the `capture` phase of event propagation).

It turns out that `mousemove` events are also being listened to, so stop them too.

The following worked for me on Firefox:

```
$('svg > g:first-of-type').bind('mouseover mousemove', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: Excellent. I updated to use `$('#' + chart_div_id + ' > div > div > svg > g:first-of-type')` because my real (non-jsfiddle) example has multiple charts).

Comment: This won't work on browsers that don't support svg but do support vml, so if that matters to you you should update to include that markup if possible.

Comment: Note: the list of events should be expanded to `mouseover mousemove mousedown mouseup click dblclick` in order to prevent crashing due to mouse clicks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm basing this answer on a solution I found here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6Y8jF/2/

The gist is to hide Google's legend and build your own.  First, disable the built-in legend by passing `legend: {position: 'none'}` in as one of the options to `chart.draw`.

In your `addDiv` function that creates the holder div for your chart, add a second element to hold your legend.

```
function addDiv(parent_id, div_id) {
    $("#" + parent_id).append('<div id="' + div_id + '" class="chart-chart"></div><ul id="legend_' + div_id + '" class="chart-legend"></ul>');
}
```

Then, in your `drawChart` function, build the legend:

```
function drawChart(chart, original_table, 
    x_attr, y_attr, x_axis_lbl, y_axis_lbl, x_min_max,
    div_id) { //pass div_id to this function to be able to get legend element

    var google_table = allSeriesToGoogleTable(original_table, 
        x_attr, y_attr, ranking_titles);

    var colors = ["#3366cc","#dc3912","#ff9900"]; //use whatever colors you like
    var options = {'chartArea':{width:"60%"}, 
        vAxis: {'title': y_axis_lbl}, 'hAxis': {'title': x_axis_lbl},
        'interpolateNulls':true,
        colors: colors, //use the same colors for the chart and the legend
        legend: {position: 'none'} //hide default legend
    };
    var legend = $('#legend_' + div_id);
    for (var i = 1; i < ranking_titles.length; i++) {
        var li = $('<li></li>'),
            marker = $('<div class="legendMarker"></div>'),
            explanation = $('<span></span>');
        explanation.text(ranking_titles[i]); // legend marker text
        marker.css( {backgroundColor: colors[i-1]} ); //marker color
        li.append(marker).append(explanation);
        legend.append(li); 
    }
    if ( ! x_min_max === undefined )
    //do something
    chart.draw( google_table, options );

    // add the data table to the chart
    chart.google_table = google_table;
}
```

Of course, make sure you include the CSS from the fiddle as well:

```
.chart-chart {
    float: left;
}
.chart-legend {
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
div.legendMarker {
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

Since you couldn't get your code into fiddle, this is untested, but it should get you 99% of the way there.

Comment: +1 Great jsfiddle, and probably the best answer; however, If it's possible to keep the original Google-rendered legend, though that would be better because your example shows some overlapping in the drawings... I've edited (jsfiddle link in edit) to show a minimal error (without your solution).

Comment: So, can you preprocess the data before drawing a chart to remove such duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

This documentation could be very helpful:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?hl=en#Configuration_Options

I think however that your code contains errors. Try debugging by starting with a basic configuration.

Comment: What happens when you place only one chart on your page?

Comment: Please see updated jsfiddle... apparently Google charts crashes when there is a duplicate point...

Answer (score 0):

If an element has more than one mouseover event, they must have been added using `addEventListener`.

And if you want to remove events added using `addEventListener`, you need `removeEventListener`. But this method needs a reference to the listener function (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener).

Then, maybe you could try [Remove all JavaScript event listeners of an element and its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222486/remove-all-javascript-event-listeners-of-an-element-and-its-children)