# Javascript unbind Anonymous callback Function

Tags: javascript, events, callback, anonymous-function

Is there any possibility to unbind anonymous callback function ...

```
link.addEventListener("click", function () {
     //Any piece of code
}, true);

link.removeEventListener("click", function () {
     //Any piece of code
});
```

Thanks,
Ajain

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3222540/551093

Comment: I'm cursious as to why this question is being asked. It seems to imply that you're aware that *named* event listeners can be removed, and that would be a simple change. Is it that you absolutely cannot change that piece of code, and you are looking for a workaround however ugly? You may be able to hijack the `addEventListener` by prototyping, to a proxy function that stores a named reference of the listener. Terrible? Yes.

Comment: [Proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/6LduX/) of what I'm talking about above.

Answer (score 3):

No. Because those to anonymouse functions are actually different. It is the same reason why `{ a: 1 } === { a: 1 }` returns false.

You need to do the following:

```
var func = function () { ... };

element.addEventListener( 'click', func, false );

element.removeEventListener( 'click', func, false );
```

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.** You can do this by saving a handle to the anonymous event handler function somewhere using `arguments.callee` and later using this saved reference to unbind the same.

```
// binding
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert('Hi'); 

    // this is where we save a handle to the anonymous handler
    // arguments.callee gives us a reference to this function
    el['_ev'] = arguments.callee;

}, false);


// unbinding
var el = document.getElementById('foo'), handler = el['_ev'];
if(handler) {

    // here we use the saved reference to unbind it        
    el.removeEventListener('click', handler);

    el['_ev'] = false;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jrXex/2/

Comment: since es5 in strict mode forbids the arguments.callee - is it right to say this solution is risky for present day development (2018)?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko - Yes you're right. This solution isn't recommended at all for new development.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are identified by pointer. You have no pointer to your anonymous function, so you have nothing to pass to remove() to tell it which function to remove.

Simply passing a duplicate function doesn't do it, because the duplicate has a different pointer.

You need to stick with assigning the function to a variable, then passing that variable to remove().

Comment: `s/pointer/reference/`